# How to set default value Jenkins active choice parameter as a script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins pipeline That has parameters defined via active choice parameter,
defining a default value is done by:

```
defaultValue: '',
```

you can put a string there or leave it empty which will give you the default result of the **groovyScript**.

I am trying to change the default parameter using a script so it will take the value using a groovy script.

This is the snippet of the relevant part of the pipeline:

```
parameters([
    extendedChoice(
        bindings: '',
        defaultValue: '',
        groovyClasspath: '',
        groovyScript:"""
            def proc = ["bash","-c","/usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls s3://Spark-Jenkins-Clusters/"].execute() | ["bash","-c","cut -c32-"].execute()
            proc.waitForOrKill(10000)
            return proc.text.tokenize()
        """,
        multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
        name: 'Choose_Cluster',
        description: 'This parameter is nice',
        quoteValue: false,
        saveJSONParameterToFile: false,
        type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        visibleItemCount: 5
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

So The way to do that is to use "defaultGroovyScript",
I didn't find it in the documentation I just saw an option in the UI and tried it and luckily it worked:

[image]

This is what I finally did:

```
parameters([
    extendedChoice(
        bindings: '',
        defaultGroovyScript: """
            def proc = ["bash","-c","/usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls s3://Spark-Jenkins-Clusters/"].execute() | \
            ["bash","-c","sort"].execute() | \
            ["bash","-c","sed 's/PRE//g'"].execute() | \
            ["bash","-c","grep main"].execute() | \
            ["bash","-c","tail -n 1"].execute() | \
            ["bash","-c","tr -d '/'"].execute()
            proc.waitForOrKill(10000)
            return proc.text.tokenize().reverse()
        """,
        groovyClasspath: '',
        groovyScript:"""
            def proc = ["bash","-c","/usr/local/bin/aws s3 ls s3://Spark-Jenkins-Clusters/"].execute() | ["bash","-c","cut -c32-"].execute()
            proc.waitForOrKill(10000)
            return proc.text.tokenize()
        """,
        multiSelectDelimiter: ',',
        name: 'Choose_Cluster',
        description: 'This parameter is nice',
        quoteValue: false,
        saveJSONParameterToFile: false,
        type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
        visibleItemCount: 5
    ),
```